# C : Return Type Defaults to Int

Tags: c, xcode, xcode4.2

I'm trying to follow "Cocoa and Objective C: Up and Running" by OReilly (a great read by the way), but I'm consistently bugged with these annoying warnings.

For example: this code segment (p.56-57)...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    int total = 81;
    float ratio = 1.618;

    char* result;
    asprintf (&result, "total: %i, ratio: %1.3f", total, ratio);

    printf ("%s \n", result);
    free (result);
}
```

Throws me this...

```
/Users/justianmeyer/Desktop/test.c:5: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
/Users/justianmeyer/Desktop/test.c: In function ‘main’:
/Users/justianmeyer/Desktop/test.c:18: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
total: 81, ratio: 1.618
```

I've been programming for a while now, but am completely new to C/Objective C as of yesterday. I've been reading that undeclared methods are expected to accept/return an int by default, but isn't the `main()` method supposed to be automatically declared? Why would it need to be defaulted to an int? Furthermore, is `main()` supposed to return an int? What's the use in that? Where is the return value received?

Also: Is there any way to create a ".c" file in XCode 4.2 without including it in a project? Right now I'm using TextMate for the examples, but I want to become as familiar with XCode as possible over the course of this book.

Comment: It's telling you that your definition of the main method is wrong. It's *supposed* to return `int`, so you have to declare it `int main()` (You're also supposed to actually return something, like `return 0;`)

Comment: That makes sense. Why is this the convention? Is it common practice to return 0 when the return isn't necessarily needed?

Comment: Just curious, did the book omit the return type?

Comment: @Firoze Lafeer: In all of the examples I have seen, the writer only specifies "main() {}" without any return type and return statement. The code snippets in the book are written without the `#include`s and `main()` function (probably to save space).

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ \[-Wreturn-type\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373538/warning-return-type-defaults-to-int-wreturn-type)

Comment: Stop reading that book: it is either too old or incites bad practices :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know ObjectiveC but in standard C you must declare the return type and the parameters for main. So:
`int main(void)` should work. Most (all) operating systems expect a return of int from main.

The return value from main is the exit code for the program to indicate whether it ended normally  or otherwise.

Comment: In older C, functions were assumed to return `int` if no type is supplied, but I think the default compiler mode in Xcode is C99, which does not have the implicit `int` rule.

Answer (score 2):

Warning are your friends.

It's telling you the function returns int but you are not returning anything so there is a potential problem.

Answer (score 2):

In older C, any function could be defined without an explicit return type, and by default, it was assumed to return `int`. This was also true for function parameters. In more recent versions of the C standard, *implicit-int* has been removed (paragraph 5 of Foreword).

Also, any function that has a return type other than `void` (meaning the function does not return a value) must have a `return` statement, otherwise your program is not conforming. Conformance is important if you want your program to run in a well-defined manner. `main` is a special exception to the `return`-statement-rule, whereby it does not *need* to have a return statement. If no return statement is provided, then the `main` function implicitly returns 0 (section 5.1.2.2.3).

Your compiler warned you that you have not explicitly specified a return type, and also that the control reaches the end of a non-void function without returning a value. The former can be easily remedied by putting `int` before `main` in your code. The latter—even though `main` is an exception to the rule—can likewise be remedied by putting in a return statement in anyway, just to be consistent with other non-void functions.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this you need int main() and return 0; at the end:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int total = 81;
    float ratio = 1.618;

    char* result;
    asprintf (&result, "total: %i, ratio: %1.3f", total, ratio);

    printf ("%s \n", result);
    free (result);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A C function can be written as

```
<return type a> <function name>( <type 1> <parameter 1>, .. ) {
   ...

   return <element of type a>;
}
```

However  can be left out, but by the set of rules your compiler plays by it is advised to specify a return type.