# warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I'm a Linux user who started learning C and I'm trying to compile this source that I typed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
        float c,d;
        c = 10215.3;
        d = c / 3;
        printf("%3.2f\n",d);
        return 0;
}
```

It compiled with this using a makefile that I wrote:

```
cc -Wall -g     printf.c   -o printf
```

but I'm getting this warning:

> printf.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]

it compiles the code and I get the desired output but I want to understand what this means

Comment: Good first question and well done on the formatting.  Welcome!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
main()
```

should be

```
int main()
```

In C89, the default return type is assumed to be `int`, that's why it works.

Comment: that worked, no warnings anymore. and I understand my mistake. thanks!

Comment: No problem. Now you might add that the compiler uses a dialect of C89 by default, apparently :)

Comment: oh C89 I kinda read something about that :) that figures. that's good to know :)

Comment: Will someone quote the standard and confirm that C99 does not allow it? :-)

Comment: Right on the money!!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

In C89, the default return type is **int**. This default was removed in C99 and compilers are helpful reminding you that your C-style with no **int** before **main()** is out of date.

See the C89 specification Section 3.5.2 "Type specifiers":

- "Each list of  type  specifiers  shall  be  one  of  the following sets: [...] + **int**, **signed**, **signed int**, *or no type specifiers*".
- And in the second paragraph of semantics: "Each of the [...] sets  designates  the same  type,  except that for bit-fields [blabla]". So this means "no type specifiers" is the same as **int**.

In C99, the part "or no type specifier" is removed. (But you can still write **signed** without the **int** part.)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Where you have defined your function. You must **decide the datatype** of your variable.

```
int function(n)
```

should be:

```
int function(int n)
```

In C89, the default return type is int. This default was removed in C99 and compilers are helpful reminding you that your C-style with no int before main() is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use void main() and remove return 0 statement. void is a keyword that represents function will not return anything

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    float c,d;
    c = 10215.3;
    d = c / 3;
    printf("%3.2f\n",d);
}
```

Comment: The standard says the return type must be `int`, see `5.1.2.2.1 Program startup` [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf).