# function warnings C: "warning: type of ‘char_array’ defaults to ‘int’"

Tags: c, function-parameter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int myprint(char_array){
    char mystring[80];
    strcat(mystring, "\n");
    printf("%s", mystring);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int count = 5;
    char letter = 'c';
    printf("decimal: %d, char: %c\n", count, letter);

    myprint("sup");

    return 0;

}
```

I get warnings on compile:

```
cchilders:~/projects/buildyourownlisp_in_C/ch3 [master]$ compile basics.c basics
basics.c: In function ‘myprint’:
basics.c:4:5: warning: type of ‘char_array’ defaults to ‘int’
 int myprint(char_array){
     ^
```

It compiles, but my `myprint` function doesn't work:

```
cchilders:~/projects/buildyourownlisp_in_C/ch3 [master]$ ./basics 
decimal: 5, char: c
```

I see this answer [warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373538/warning-return-type-defaults-to-int-wreturn-type) but doesn't apply to me since I did declare `int main(...)`

I also see this declaration of functions:

```
return_type function_name( parameter list ) {
   body of the function
}
```

And for `myprint` I declare as taking `int` and return `0`. What does this warning mean and why doesn't my function work? Thank you

ANSWER:

```
void myprint(char mystring[]){
    strcat(mystring, "\n");
    printf("%s", mystring);

}
```

quiets the warnings, but causes `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Changing to

```
void myprint(char[] mystring){
    strcat(mystring, "\n");
    printf("%s", mystring);

}
```

makes it worse:

```
cchilders:~/projects/buildyourownlisp_in_C/ch3 [master]$ cc -std=c99 -Wall basics.c -o basics
basics.c:4:21: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘mystring’
 void myprint(char[] mystring;){
                     ^
basics.c: In function ‘main’:
basics.c:15:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘myprint’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     myprint("sup");
     ^
```

I also tried

```
void myprint(char[] mystring;){...
```

and

```
void myprint(char[] mystring,){...
```

Comment: There's a wayward semi-colon in there:  void myprint(char[] mystring;){

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you didn't specify a type for `char_array`, so it is assumed to be `int`.  Changing it to `char char_array[]` fixes this.

Your other problem is that you're passing a string constant (`"sup"`) to this function and are then attempting to modify it.  String constants are stored in a read-only section of memory, so you can't modify it.

Given that you're only printing the string with a newline, you can do this instead:

```
void myprint(char mystring[]){
    printf("%s\n", mystring);
}
```

Comment: So how would I add the \n manually? Make a newly named variable inside the function and add \n?

Comment: @codyc4321 You could, but if the change isn't being seen outside the function, there's no point in using a temp variable.

Answer (score 3):

You are not providing a data type for char_array in

```
int myprint(char_array)
```

You need char * or whatever you want it to be.

Comment: changing to `char_array*` and then `char_array[]` didn't help either

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, function definitions should be like

```
return-type function-name ( parameter-type parameter-name, parameter-type parameter-name)
{ ... }
```

You did not specify either a parameter type or a parameter name. If you mean char_array to mean a type, you need to define it first, using a typedef or a struct or something else. If you mean char_array to be a parameter name, you need to specify its type, as

```
char[] char_array
```

say. Also, in this case, you do not actually use the variable char array anywhere in the function myprint. So the argument "sup" is not being used at all.

After edit to the question:

Try

```
char str[] = "sup";
myprint(str);
```

instead. As far as I know, you can't pass a string (a character array) by value.

Comment: I see the mismatch now, but changing syntax made it worse, please see above

Comment: @codyc4321 try what I suggested after the edit, above.

Answer (score 2):

```
int myprint(char_array)
```

What *type* has the parameter with name `char_array`? Because you didn't specify it, the compiler assumed it to be an `int`. Luckily it's warning you about that.

Don't rely on such behaviour, though. (I don't know whether this is still legal in C11 for example) Just write correct function declarations, including parameter types.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type of the parameters you expect to be passed to the function. There are mistakes in the function too. `char_array` is of  `char*` type. You need to copy every part of the passed array to your local array, THEN only can you call printf for this function to work